# Recursive Tree Rendering in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a recursive tree with leafs stored in an array which is rendered in Compose with each node as a separate Compose Function, everything updates correctly in case of adding a leaf to the end of the array, but when I delete a leaf or move one down I get incorrect updates, it feels like Compose is caching somehow the nodes, although I'm rewriting everything.

For example if I move a leaf down the data doesn't reflect the change, if I delete the last leaf it's ok, but if I delete one in the middle of the array the last one will be shown as removed, even though the underlying data is correct.

```
data class IngredientNode(
    var ingredient: Ingredient,
    @JsonIgnore
    var parent: IngredientNode? = null,
    var children: SnapshotStateList<IngredientNode> = mutableStateListOf<IngredientNode>()
)
```

On refresh I'm rewriting each node and children with `*.copy()`

I've been trying to debug this for a while and seemingly the background data is fine not sure how to force Compose to rerender the data correctly.

If I navigate to another compose page and come back the rendering fixes itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I found out that I was storing my composable items not as MutableState, hence the update issues, after separating all required vars into MutableState variables, everything works as expected.